# How do I use form #states greater than x?

Tags: forms

I have a Drupal 8 site. How do I use `#states` to show an field if the value of another field is greater than one of my variables?

The code below is for =$chkval

```
$chkval = 4;
// This would be set by a database query

'#states' => array(
    'visible'=> array(
        ':input[name = 'actual_reps'] => array('value' => $chkval)
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't think that drupal states support it.

Comment: All This magic happens in \core\misc\states.js so have a look at it and maybe you'll figure out how to extend it and if not it should not be hard to write custom JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Drupal does not support that.

> The following states may be applied to an element:
>
> - enabled
> - disabled
> - required
> - optional
> - visible
> - invisible
> - checked
> - unchecked
> - expanded
> - collapsed
>
> The following states may be used in remote conditions:
>
> - empty
> - filled
> - checked
> - unchecked
> - expanded
> - collapsed
> - value
>
> The following states exist for both elements and remote conditions,
> but are not fully implemented and may not change anything on the
> element:
>
> - relevant
> - irrelevant
> - valid
> - invalid
> - touched
> - untouched
> - readwrite
> - readonly
>
> When referencing select lists and radio buttons in remote conditions,
> a 'value' condition must be used:
>
> @code
>
> '#states' => array(
>
> // Show the settings if 'bar' has been selected for 'foo'.
>
> 'visible' => array(
>
> ```
> ':input[name="foo"]' => array('value' => 'bar'),
> ```
>
> ),
>
> ),
>
> @endcode

You can see state support value, but **value is array**, so can't use condition of value.

See the [process states documentation page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this and regex by attaching the webform.states library to your form.

In your custom_module.libraries.yml:

```
webform.states:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.states.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - webform/webform.behaviors
    - core/drupal.states
```

Then in your form, simply add:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom_module/webform.states';
```

Now you can use all of these:

```
  Drupal.states.Dependent.comparisons.Object = function (reference, value) {
    if ('pattern' in reference) {
      return (new RegExp(reference['pattern'])).test(value);
    }
    else if ('!pattern' in reference) {
      return !((new RegExp(reference['!pattern'])).test(value));
    }
    else if ('less' in reference) {
      return (value !== '' && parseFloat(reference['less']) > parseFloat(value));
    }
    else if ('less_equal' in reference) {
      return (value !== '' && parseFloat(reference['less_equal']) >= parseFloat(value));
    }
    else if ('greater' in reference) {
      return (value !== '' && parseFloat(reference['greater']) < parseFloat(value));
    }
    else if ('greater_equal' in reference) {
      return (value !== '' && parseFloat(reference['greater_equal']) <= parseFloat(value));
    }
    else if ('between' in reference || '!between' in reference) {
      if (value === '') {
        return false;
      }

      var between = reference['between'] || reference['!between'];
      var betweenParts = between.split(':');
      var greater = betweenParts[0];
      var less = (typeof betweenParts[1] !== 'undefined') ? betweenParts[1] : null;
      var isGreaterThan = (greater === null || greater === '' || parseFloat(value) >= parseFloat(greater));
      var isLessThan = (less === null || less === '' || parseFloat(value) <= parseFloat(less));
      var result = (isGreaterThan && isLessThan);
      return (reference['!between']) ? !result : result;
    }
    else {
      return reference.indexOf(value) !== false;
    }
  };
```

Like so:

```
'#states' => [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="custom_field"]' => ['value' => ['greater_equal' => '40']],
   ],
]
```