# How do I perform a "contains" match with #states?

Tags: webforms, emails

I use the same form for different events. Previously I have set up a conditional email to be sent based on the exact title of the event. However, I would like to have the conditional email be sent based on one specific word in the event title. Is there a way to set up the logic to base it on a partial text match? The attached image, is an example of when I do an exact title match. However, I would like to set up the logic to be conditional on a single word, "MBA" to catch all signups related to any event related to "MBA" instead of setting up the logic for each specific event.

Essentially, I would like the option of "contains" instead of "is" but not sure how to write it.

[image: logic example]

Comment: Drupal Core's Form API has provides discreet states: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields#statesproperty Because I see YAML above: is this a Drupal Webform?

Comment: This question is similar: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187521/8-form-states-greater-than-x

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 'Pattern' trigger which can be a string or regular expression.

```
textfield:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': textfield
  '#description': 'Enter a value that contains the letter a.'
markup:
  '#type': webform_markup
  '#states':
    visible:
      ':input[name="textfield"]':
        value:
          pattern: a
  '#markup': 'Text field contains the letter <strong>A.</strong>'
```